# What does Raw Read Error Rate mean in SSD SMART?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, diagnostic, smart

I downloaded trial version of [HD Tune Pro](http://www.hdtune.com/) and I'm using it to benchmark my hard drives. In Health tab of SSD I found Raw Read Error Rate property. What does this property say about my hard drive?

[image]

OCZ tool shows only `114 total ECC and RAISE errors`. But what does Data column in HD Tune mean? Why the description says that disk had 89.970.873 read errors? It is new disk. I installed it yesterday and it is passing all diagnostic tests in [SeaTools](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/downloads/seatools), Performance tests in HD Tune Pro and common check in Chkdsk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HD Tune data looks quite suspect. For example, I don't believe that you had a temperature peak of 129 degrees celcius. And as you say, the ECC recovered rate is simply ridiculous.

Since this is an OCZ disk, I would go with OCZ tool, and take its findings as the correct ones.

If you are worried about 114 ECC and RAISE errors, the best is to get in touch with [OCZ Support](http://www.ocztechnology.com/support/), and ask if they advise to use the warranty to exchange the disk. Their answer, if positive, will give you the necessary ammunition when dealing with your vendor.

Comment: The Current and Worst values for temperature can never be read directly from SMART data. The software has to convert it into a readable value, sometimes this varies by drive too so the software has to be coded for certain drives. I don't know about HD Tune Pro but I know Smartmontools can output the correct temperature for most drives.

Comment: Can you also explain what does Raw Read Error Rate mean?

Comment: It means the drive has bad blocks that prevent the computer from reading its contents normally. A high rate means that the disk is failing, which is why I suggested to contact Support, just in case.

Comment: @harrymc, the temperature field is probably reporting in Fahrenheit.

Answer (score 2):

Just like to add that the errors are correctable, so programs don't get to see them but all the same, I would not expect to see any real read errors from SSDs. I would seek further clarification from the manufacturer.
Hopefully one day we'll have SSDs that don't wear out.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the temperature field. The *Raw/Data* column should have a normal temperature value and the *Current/Worst* columns should have a “strange”, high value. See several examples below.

Clearly, HD Tune is doing some fancy work and/or pre-processing of the data before formatting and showing it, and it is not working out quite right. In fact, looking at the raw value of the temperature field, HD Tune is interpreting, and maybe even *reading* the data incorrectly.

Try another [SMART tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_S.M.A.R.T._tools) (preferably an OCZ one like Harry said). I like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php). Use that to see what the values are and if the numbers are still weird (eg the temperature field is still showing values similar to 30-129 in the *Current/Worst* columns and a huge number in the *Raw/Data* column). If they are, then it could be your drive; either it’s SMART circuitry is damaged, or it simply **requires** custom SMART software. However requiring custom SMART software highly unlikely since it is a standard and would be very user-unfriendly.

At least [one other person](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?76859-OCZ-SSD-S.M.A.R.T.-readings-and-RMA) has similar, strange results (see bottom image); though they may also have a defective drive.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

[image]